# How powerful is dart?

Tags: javascript, dart

I am having some difficulty understanding dartlang and its uses. Can I use it as a backend as well as a front end or do I implement the back end with nodejs php etc? Also, has anyone tackled user management with dartlang?

Comment: The plan is to use dart client side in the browser and server side. But there isn't a stable version yet. There is an unstable server SDK and a dartium, a chromium with dart vm, in development but there are no release dates or announcements from other browser developers.

Comment: It will be over 9000! in few years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Dart on the front end and back end. You can write your own server, or use one that somebody else has written, for instance the [Start](https://github.com/lvivski/start) server. For user management, you can start with one of the Dart database packages ([MySQL](https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky), [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/xxgreg/postgresql), [MongoDB](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart), etc.).

However, the Dart server experience is not currently the most mature. For serious projects, it is probably better to go with a an existing non-Dart solution (as you mentioned, NodeJS, PHP, or any of the many other server solutions).

Until Dart 1.0, the Dart team is focused on the client-side experience, so this is not likely to change in the near future.